# Is it fine to use old kernel with a newer operating system?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I had a system running Ubuntu-16.04 with a customized RT kernel version 4.4.
After upgrading the operating system to Ubuntu-20.04, I'm still running the same kernel due to its customizations.
Is it ok to run the new OS with the old kernel?

Comment: "operating system" ?? Could you please tell us what you precisely mean ?

Comment: What sort of customization? if it's just the PREEMPT_RT support, there are much newer -rt kernels available, that are as stable, more secure and likely better overall... are you using other out-or-tree patches or something? (have they not been ported / rewritten for newer kernels?)

Comment: The customization is related to intel up-board . more info about that here: https://github-wiki-see.page/m/up-board/up-community/wiki/Ubuntu_20.04

Comment: the kernel code should also be patched according to the (unknown to me) changes that the up-board community has done. they have a repo 'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:aaeon-cm/5.4-upboard' that enables me to install 'linux-generic-hwe-18.04-5.4-upboard'. but there is no RT one available.
the RT kernel that I had on the old ubuntu16 was provided by this link: 'https://github.com/qiayuanliao/Ubuntu-RT-UP-Board\'

Comment: I already compiled a RT Kernel version 5.4.170, but using that kernel the /dev/spidev2 is not there anemore

Comment: I could fllow the steps in 'https://github.com/qiayuanliao/Ubuntu-RT-UP-Board#Build-from-generic-kernel-step-by-step'. But I'm afraid the patch in step 3 won't work on the new kernel code since it is based on the kernel version 4.4!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be lots of security updates since that 6 year old kernel was released. It's also crawling all over EOL. For that reason alone, no.

There is also the possibility that new syscalls will have been created and if any of the newly installed software tries to call them, then that will fail.

You really want to update the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to apply the patches written for kernel v4.4 into the kernel v5.4! but there are some files that do not exist in the new kernel and it is hard to figure out how to continue applying the patches. I am forced to use the old kernel now. My question then would be, with the above situation, if my robot continues to work as expected, should I be worried that in the long run there will be problems? for example, the system crash that would cause the robot to fail?

Comment: @hmojtaba That is not a question that any of us can answer.

Comment: I guess you are right :) later in the future, I will update my experience with this setup.